# How can I parse an ElementList with Path?

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

Here's a snippet of XML that I'd like to deserialize with SimpleFramework:

```
<rs><r>
   <id>23</id>
   <bar>blargh</bar>
   <c><v>value 1</v></c>
   <c><v>value 2</v></c>
   <c><v>yet another value</v></c>
   <c><v>moar value</v></c>
</r></rs>
```

What I would like to end up with is an ElementList containing the contents of all the  elements. I'm imagining something like:

```
@Root(strict=false)
public static class Foo {
    @Element(name="id")
    public int id;
    @Element(name="bar")
    public String info;
    @Path("c")
    @ElementList(entry="v", inline=true, required=false, empty = false)
    public List<String> values;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is reach down past the "c" element and directly into the "v" element for each member of the list. The above code doesn't do it. I want the @Path("c") statement to apply to each element in the list, but I can't figure out how to make the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. `<rs><r>...</r></rs>` are *nested tags* of the *root* element (not
   sure if `@Path` can handle this ...)
2. the two tags of each entry (`<c><v>...</v></c>`) are not possible
   through `@ElementList` annotations (and `@Path` can't be set for each entry)

As a solution you can write two ***wrapper classes***:

- One, that wraps the root-node
- Another one, that's put in the list, wrapping each a entry

And here comes the implementation:

## Class `FooWrapper`

This class wraps a `Foo` class; you get rs-tag through the wrapper and the r-tag with the actual object.

```
@Root(name = "rs")
public class FooWrapper
{
    @Element(name = "r", required = true)
    private Foo f;


    public FooWrapper(Foo f) // Required just in case you want to serialize this object
    {
        this.f = f;
    }

    FooWrapper() { } // At least a default ctor is required for deserialization
}
```

## Class `Foo`

Nothing special here. Only the type of the list entries is changed to the `EntryWrapper`.

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class Foo /* A */
{
    @Element(name = "id")
    public int id; /* B */
    @Element(name="bar")
    public String info;
    @ElementList(entry="c", inline=true, required=false, empty = false)
    public List<EntryWrapper> values; // Replacing the String with the EntryWrapper

    // ...
}
```

- `/* A */`: In your code, this was `static` too, i've just removed it since i put it into a own class file.
- `/* B */`: Better: encapsulate the fields, make them `private` and write getter / setter.

## Class `EntryWrapper`

Each entry in the list is wrapped into such a wrapper object. Btw. no need to expose this class `public`.

```
public class EntryWrapper
{
    @Element(name = "v")
    private String value;


    public EntryWrapper(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    EntryWrapper() { } // Once again, at least one default ctor is required for deserialization

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yea, this is how I implemented it while waiting for a better answer. I was hoping to avoid the EntryWrapper class for just a single value. It's not a big deal for a level or two down, but I think I'm going to have cases where I need to parse several nested elements, each with a single child, until I get to a value. I'll mark this as accepted. I guess there's nothing better.

Comment: If you get really difficult elements, you can thing about a `Converter`. See simple's documentation for more informations and examples.